# Failed to run Cognitive-Face-Python-master test

Tags: python-2.7, azure-cognitive-services, face-api

I'm exploring  the Face API. I'm using a GUI sample.

GUI link: https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Face-Python

This error occurs when I run the sample:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Tin Central\programming\DOAN\Cognitive-Face-Python-
master\Cognitive-Face-Python-master\sample\view\__init__.py", line 101, in 
OnInit
frame = MyFrame(None)
File "D:\Tin Central\programming\DOAN\Cognitive-Face-Python-
master\Cognitive-Face-Python-master\sample\view\__init__.py", line 80, in 
__init__
self.book = MyLabelBook(self)
File "D:\Tin Central\programming\DOAN\Cognitive-Face-Python-
master\Cognitive-Face-Python-master\sample\view\__init__.py", line 31, in 
__init__
subscription_panel = SubscriptionPanel(self)
File "D:\Tin Central\programming\DOAN\Cognitive-Face-Python-
master\Cognitive-Face-Python-master\sample\view\panel_subscription.py", line 
42, in __init__
subgridsizer = wx.GridSizer(rows=2, cols=2)
TypeError: GridSizer(): arguments did not match any overloaded call:
overload 1: 'rows' is not a valid keyword argument
overload 2: 'rows' is not a valid keyword argument
overload 3: not enough arguments
overload 4: not enough arguments
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably installed wxPython 4, which is still in beta.

You need to install wxPython 3.0.2 by going here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/wxpython/files/wxPython/3.0.2.0/.

Make sure you pick the .exe corresponding to the Python version you have (32-bit or 64-bit).

The full instructions to run the sample app are [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Face-Python#running-the-sample).